# Migration from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2007

We are planning to do migration from our SharePoint 2007 (1.5 TB) to SharePoint online. We are evaluating Metalogix and Sharegate for Our migration.

So we want to hear from you on the recommendation between Metalogix or Sharegate. Also if you list down the high level features which are possible or not possible between these tools that will be really great.

Thanks,

Praveen

Answer (score 1):

We evaluate both tools last year and at that time we decided to use the meta logic.

It is expensive as compare to share gate but full fill all our needs.

Also take a look of this post, will help u on comparison.

http://sharepoint-community.net/m/blogpost?id=6614983%3ABlogPost%3A123929